# I want Bootstrap Tags Input for Date Picker in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, input, tags

In my project I implemented Date picker. So picked years want to be filled into a input filed as tags. Here are the code segments I implemented.

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <form id="sbYearRevForm" class="form-horizontal" method="post">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                 Year(s)<span style="color: red"> *</span>
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <!-- <input type="tel" pattern='\d{9}'  id="msisdn" name="msisdn" placeholder="Subscriber No.(77xxxxxxx)" class="form-control input-sm" required> -->
                <input type="text" id="yearPicker" name="years" class="form-control input-sm" data-role="tagsinput" required>
            </div>
        </div>



    </form>
<div/>
```

Following are the JQuery two functions i implemented.

```
$('#yearPicker').datepicker({
    minViewMode: 2,
    format: 'yyyy',
    multidate: true,
    endDate: '+0y',
    startDate: '2016'
});

$('#yearPicker').tagsinput({
    typeaheadjs: {
        minViewMode: 2,
        format: 'yyyy',
        multidate: true,
        endDate: '+0y',
        startDate: '2016'
    }
});
```

Why this code segment not functioning? can anyone help me here?

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: @irsha____D No actually no any errors but here date values not as tags inside the input field

Comment: what do u mean by `as tags inside the input field`?? please clarify

Comment: for the example please check this link http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#yearPicker').tagsinput({
    typeaheadjs: {
        minViewMode: 2,
        format: 'yyyy',
        multidate: true,
        endDate: '+0y',
        startDate: '2016'
    }
});
$('#yearPicker').on('beforeItemRemove', function(event) {
  console.log("Deleting");

});
 $('.bootstrap-tagsinput input[type="text"]').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    format: 'yyyy',
    multidate: true,
    endDate: '+0y',
    startDate: '2016',
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
       $('#yearPicker').tagsinput('add', dateText);
       $('.bootstrap-tagsinput input[type="text"]').datepicker('setDate', null);
  }
});


});
```

```css
#yearPicker{
 min-width:200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.js"></script>


<div class="panel-body">
    <form id="sbYearRevForm" class="form-horizontal" method="post">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                 Year(s)<span style="color: red"> *</span>
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <!-- <input type="tel" pattern='\d{9}'  id="msisdn" name="msisdn" placeholder="Subscriber No.(77xxxxxxx)" class="form-control input-sm" required> -->
                <input type="text" id="yearPicker" name="years" class="form-control input-sm" data-role="tagsinput"  required>
               
            </div>
        </div>



    </form>
<div/>
```

Here is the solution for you. First of all create tagsinput then use this selecter `.bootstrap-tagsinput input[type="text"]` to create date picker

Comment: if i add above script and links date picker and other functions not working.

Comment: In my project this is how it used <script src="<c:url value="/resources/vendor/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"/>"></script>

Comment: i cant see the any difference here

Comment: Here i used cdn url for fetching library remotely. You can download those files using the cdn url

Comment: Cant i keep both downloaded and URL in the same file?

Comment: i updated the code sightly. but few modifications there. have you seen in a tag there is a little x button when i press it tag will be closed. so here it is missing. any suggestions?

Comment: You can use url,and downloaded resources simultaneouly. The only requirement is that url needs active internet connection.

Comment: Bro thank you. you helped me a lot here. thanks. um very new to the coding that is the case here. anyway thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad to help you go ahead happy coding.

Comment: i want to ask something related to coding bcz um struggling at coding. any social media or email that i can contact you ?

Comment: mailbox4sumesh@gmail.com feel free to contact me.

Comment: @L.Anush The close button missing is due to a css file i updated the answer again please check. https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.css

Comment: No. close button solved what i had to do is add inputtag.css to the code

Answer (score 0):

For this, You can try the followings :

```
<div class="form-group datePicker">
     <label for="deliveryDate" class="bmd-label-floating">Delivery Date</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" value="12/07/2018" name="deliveryDate" id="deliveryDate">
     <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Add this following script and above html to make it working

```
(function($) {
  $(".datepicker").datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
  });
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: I want date values in the input field as tags

Comment: check this link http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/